# How to set a Modal popup with an image in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, popup, modalpopupextender

I have an Image class in React, and I have a button that should implement expand on click, on every image. I decided to use a Modal popup so when I click, the Image will show bigger in the Modal popup. I find it hard to set the Modal as an image.

Thank you in advance.

This is from the `Image` class in React:

```
<FontAwesome
  className="image-icon"
  name="expand"
  title="expand"
  onClick={this.showModal}
/>
<Modal show={this.state.isExpand} handleClose={this.hideModal} />
```

Modal:

```
const Modal = ({ handleClose, show }) => {
  const showHideClassName = show ? 'modal display-block' : 'modal display-none';
  return (
    <div className={showHideClassName}>
      <section className="modal-main">
        <button onClick={handleClose}>close</button>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi - could you add a little more detail about the specific problem? Is it that you don't know where to put the <img src={url} etc... > tag in the Modal and to pass the `url` variable in?

Answer (score 6):

Try this sample code. Here is a link to the example ImageComponent https://codesandbox.io/s/4xnxqz0ylx

```
export default class ImageComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { isOpen: false };

  handleShowDialog = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
    console.log('cliked');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          className="small"
          src="/Anj.png"
          onClick={this.handleShowDialog}
          alt="no image"
        />
        {this.state.isOpen && (
          <dialog
            className="dialog"
            style={{ position: 'absolute' }}
            open
            onClick={this.handleShowDialog}
          >
            <img
              className="image"
              src="/Anj.png"
              onClick={this.handleShowDialog}
              alt="no image"
            />
          </dialog>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```